# How can I style android spinner prompt

Tags: android, android-spinner, prompt

I have developed one example.

Here I have to style a spinner prompt. Please help me. How can I style it?

This is my **string.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, CustomizedListView!</string>
<string name="app_name">CustomizedListView</string>
<string name="status_prompt">Choose a Status</string>
</resources>
```

This code is used on my main.xml:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="106dp"
    android:layout_y="100dp"
    android:prompt="@string/status_prompt" 
    android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"/>
```

Here I wish to change the background color and `textSize`, `textStyle` on below image. How can I change this.

[image: spinner prompt]

**EDIT:**
I have added the below code in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="spinner_style">                        
<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#040404</item>
<item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
<item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

also added below line on the main.xml for spinner:

```
  style="@style/spinner_style"
```

But it also did not work for me. How can I style the spinner prompt message.

**EDIT:**

This is my java code for `ArrayAdaper`:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    }
```

How can I set the prompt style here.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the prompt, you need to use a similar method to what @aswin-kumar suggested, but with a separate style for the first element of the drop down:

First, extend `ArrayAdapter` and call it `CustomArrayAdapter`:
package com.example.project;

```
package com.example.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


// I extend this using ArrayAdapter<String>, but you can use anything as the type
// parameter, or parameterize it as necessary.
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private String title;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context aContext, int aTextViewResource, List<String> aOptions, String title) {
        super(aContext, aTextViewResource, aOptions);
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int aPosition, View aConvertView, ViewGroup aParent) {

        LinearLayout v = null;

        if (aPosition == 0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown_header, aParent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_item);
            tv.setText(getItem(aPosition));
        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown_item, aParent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_item);
            tv.setText(getItem(aPosition));
            tv.setHeight((int) (tv.getTextSize() * 2));
        }


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return title;
        }
        return super.getItem(position - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return position != 0;
    }
}
```

Now, use the following layout for your `dropdown_header.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="9pt" />

    <!-- This adds a black separator line between the title and the items. You can remove
         if you want -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The form view layout file (form_view_layout.xml):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_dialog_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="9pt" />
```

The spinner layout file (`spinner_layout.xml`):

```
 <Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Now, attach the new adapter to your `Spinner`:

```
CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(aActivity, R.layout.form_view_layout, aModel.getEnumerableOptions(), aModel.getTitle());
View parentView = aActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, aParent, false);

spinner = (Spinner) parentView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally, add the strings you want to display to your spinner adapter, `adapter`, and style the appropriate files, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own Adapter for the spinner which extends from `ArrayAdapter`. The `getView()` function is called when the layout system indicates that the view you've shown in pic needs to be drawn. You can override this and add textSize, textStyle, etc.

Update: a rough code sample would be:

```
private class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // apply the style and sizes etc to the Text view from this view v
        // like ((TextView)v).setTextSize(...) etc
        return v;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // this is for each of the drop down resource that is created. 
            // you can style these things too
        }
}
```

Use this as the Adapter for your spinner:

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter(ActivityName.this,
                    R.layout.spinner_item,
                    R.id.spinner_item_TextView, 
                    listOfItemsInSpinner));
```

Comment: in above code only change the style for spinner items only.i wish to change the spinner prompt style.