# How to change Spinner popup Title background?

Tags: android, android-spinner

If I just need to change the Spinner popup Title bar background, what should I do? The only way is to make a customize spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a custom spinner. The following link may help you to create it. [change the spinner title bar style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951203/change-the-spinner-title-bar-style)

Comment: The link your provide seems only change the spinner popup item rows, not the Title bar at all. There seem no such function? Here is another link for [ArrayAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913704/how-can-i-style-android-spinner-prompt/12914526#12914526).