# How to make customize prompt for spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to change spinner prompt background.Or want to make customise prompt.But i do not want to use with dialog so want to change in prompt property.
 Is it possible to change it?
[image]

Thnks in advance.

Comment: I guess when you search for `custom spinner android` you would get many results such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I do not want to customize spinner but I want to customize prompt of a spinner.

Comment: is this what u are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913704/how-can-i-style-android-spinner-prompt ?

Comment: Thnks you for a reply , Your given reference link I have already visited that is for customizing spinner layout not prompt.

Comment: Could you share you code for the spinner? the layout? i can give it a go!

Comment: JAVA FILE :

 ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = newArrayAdapter<String(context,
    R.layout.custom_text_for_oppo, TagList);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

XML FILE :

<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/oppo_tag"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_corner_edittext"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />